# When I copy and paste a link, it replaces it with random characters

Tags: windows-10, copy-paste, clipboard, windows-10-v2004, random

Copied link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mergers_and_acquisitions_by_microsoft

Pasted link:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LdcxhrrmCTdLqs67V5Ps5omaHbbapv5as2y_microsoft

My win 10 replace an original link with this "random generated" link.

[Example Gif](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/714411217049092129/763875926479732746/2020-10-08_23-18-31.gif)

Any idea how to fix this permanently?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which applications you are copying from and pasting into, but if it is allowed, you could try right-clicking and pasting as plain text.

Comment: If I copy the link from Opera, Firefox, Chrome (or from any browser). The link above will be created. I tried the "Right click -> copy & paste" and the "CTRL + C & CTRL + V" methods...but both have the same result and It doesn't matter where I paste the link (e.g.: Notepad++, Word...etc) [Example Gif](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/714411217049092129/763875926479732746/2020-10-08_23-18-31.gif)

Comment: So if you paste into Notepad++ (which is text only) you also get "garbage"?

Comment: The problem is only when copying URLs from browsers?
I suggest you narrow down the problem in the question, not in comments.